# Django- allow both images and text to be uploaded at the same time?

Tags: django, django-models, file-upload, django-forms

I would like to have a field in my `models.py` and `forms.py` to have the option to upload either photos or text, or both at the same time.  Currently, I use a WYSIWYG editor to do that.  How would I modify my models so that I can have that option? Here is my code so far:

models.py

```
class Problem(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(null = False, unique = True, max_length = 255)
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    free = models.CharField(max_length = 1, choices = Free)

    #problem when introducing UUID field
    traceID = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable = True)

    #use meta tags to optimize SEO
    metaTags = models.TextField(default = "")

    questionToProblem = models.TextField()

    #migration with CKEDitor is 0023_alter_problem_solutiontoproblem.py
    solutionToProblem = RichTextUploadingField(blank = True, null = True)
```

The field `solutiontoProblem` is where I have my text editor- I want to have the field so that it accepts both text and images.  Similarily, here is my `forms.py`:

forms.py

```
class ProblemForm(forms.ModelForm):
    slug = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'link'}))
    topic = forms.ModelChoiceField(label = "Topic", queryset = Topic.objects.all())
    metaTags = forms.CharField(label = "Meta Tags", widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={"rows" : 15, "cols" : 90}))
    questionToProblem = forms.CharField(label = "Question", widget = QuestionFormWithPreview(attrs={'id' : 'mathInputForQuestion', 'cols': 90, 'rows': 15, 'onkeyup':'PreviewQuestion.Update()'}))
    solutionToProblem = forms.CharField(widget = CKEditorUploadingWidget(), label = "Solution")

    class Meta:
        model = Problem
        fields = ('metaTags', 'questionToProblem', 'solutionToProblem')
```

How would I get it so that the field in both models and forms can accept image files or text, or both?

Comment: I think `RichTextUploadingField` supports uploading images by pasting them into text. Are you looking for something else?

Comment: I'm trying to look for a custom solution that doesn't rely on libraries

Comment: Then you may have just `models.TextField`  for text and `models.ImageField` for a picture. I.e. two fields. Is it fine?

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but is it possible to make it so that there's only one field instead?

Comment: Even if yes - it's not very nice to keep different types of data in one field. See my answer for more thoughts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put both fields in additional model and point to it from your model:

```
class Solution(models.Model):
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)

    def clean(self):
        if self.decription is None and self.image is None:
            raise ValidationError('Please provide image of text')
        super().clean()


class Problem(forms.Model):
    ...
    solutionToProblem = models.ForeignKey(Solution, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

And then you create a form for `Solution`. Might be as simple as that:

```
class SolutionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Solution
        fields = ('description', 'image')
```

So this will be technically **one field** from Problem model perspective but with two properties. And how to represent/handle them you can decide on your frontend (e.g. show only image when there is no text, etc)